# Spring Security Authorization to an url based on Claim Value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am developing my web app based on OIDC using spring boot.

I am trying to authorize an url based on the claim value returned from oAuth Server. Here is my case.

I have an admin url - /admin, and have a custom claim along with default claims, setup in the okta . I am getting authenticated and after that from the userInfo url I will get the claim values and it contains the list of Groups (Like prov1, prov2, ProvAdmin).

From the above claim- Groups, I have to authorize the user to my /admin usl if the above list contains ProvAdmin group. so basically if the user contains the group - ProvAdmin, then only the user will be authorized to the /admin url

Below is my springSecurity config

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http.authorizeRequests().mvcMatchers("/admin")
.anyRequest().authenticated()
.and()
.oauth2Login()
.loginPage("/customOAuth2Login_Okta").permitAll()
.and()
.logout()
.logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/performLogOut")).permitAll()
}
```